How to score questions with a non-integer number with exams2blackboard
I want to score each question with 0.5 points, but on execution:
exams2blackboard("VAEspVarianzaDesvOP2", n=3, points= 0.5, mchoice = list(enumerate = FALSE), converter = "pandoc", eval = list(partial = T, negative = -1, rule = "false")) 

The error is as follows:
Error en sprintf("%d.0", sum(points)):
invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects


Hi Amelia, welcome to SO. In order to get help on this platform, endeavor to make your problem reproducible by other developers by including necessary code and data. However, I think you are encountering that error because you are passing a floating-point number to the point =  argument when it expects a numeric value. Try changing 0.5 to 1 and see if you still encounter the error.

The error does not exist with an integer (1, 2, 3......) but the error exists with 0.5, 1.5 or 2.5.......
I want each question to be worth 0.5 points and not 1 point.

I'm not sure whether Blackboard permits non-integer points in the QTI XML. But let's try. I'll let you know when you can install the modified development version of the exams package.

Agreed. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether Blackboard Learn and/or Blackboard Ultra can actually deal with fractional points but I cannot test this myself. So for the moment I have replace the sprintf("%d.0", sum(points)) with sprintf("%.3f", sum(points)) which rounds floats to three decimal places.
Example: To try this out, please use the current development version from R-universe (our usual development server, R-Forge, currently hangs) and try your example above. Or instead use one of the built-in exercises:
install.packages("exams", repos = "https://zeileis.R-universe.dev")
library("exams")
exams2blackboard("deriv2.Rmd", points = 0.5)


Perfect. Above I have put the result.

Perfect, thanks for the feedback. I've documented this now in the NEWS file of the development version.
